# GoogleMobileAdsが実装できない

Tags: swift, ios, admob

GoogleMobileAdsを実装して広告を表示させたいと思っていますがうまくいきません｡
GoogleMobileAdsの設定等は自身で調べて何とかできました｡

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

自身の見解では

override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

class ViewController: UIViewController,
AVAudioPlayerDelegate {

等の階層等の問題ではないかと思っております｡
初めて2つのSDKを使用するので困惑しております｡

ご存知の方おりましたらご教授頂けたら幸いでございます｡
どうぞよろしくお願いいたします｡

Comment: コンパイルエラーメッセージを読むと分かると思います。
英単語が分からなければ、辞書を引きましょう。

Answer (score 2):

invalid redeclaration od 'ViewController'
をまず解決しないといけないのでは
同じクラスを宣言していて２回目で！のエラーになっています

それでrequestもbannerViewも２つ目のクラスからは見えていないのでエラーでしょう